# Developing a desktop environment for linux

Tags: linux

I want to build a new desktop environment for linux like KDE or GNOME, not that much complex, i just want a new windowing system, a new desktop, just like that with some simple functionalities.

But the problem is i don't know where to start. Is it possible to use toolkits like Qt or wxWidgets for this purpose or should i start from anything other? I can program in languages c, c++, java ...

Is this X11 or X Window System have any relation with this. Can anybody tell me where should i start.

Comment: Um... this is a very broad question, I'm not sure whether you'll be able to get a really useful answer - but you never know. (FWIW, KDE is built on Qt, for an example of a DE that uses a graphical toolkit.)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky What a gentle comment!

Comment: I'd strongly consider taking an existing minimal desktop and starting from there. "Just" a new windowing system implies you might be better off standing on the shoulders of existing work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desktop environments on Linux consist of many interconnected components. You should start by reading about how existing desktop environments work: what components they contain, and how they work together.

The information you need is on the internet. Look at Wikipedia (for example, the [Desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) page, [Windowing system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system) and [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) pages). Look at [freedesktop.org](http://www.freedesktop.org/), and its [Specifications](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications) page. **Google for other information**.

The fact that you're asking questions about whether X11 or X Window System has any relation to this task indicates that you don't yet have a good understanding of the main software components of a Linux desktop. Luckily, that problem is easy to solve: you just have to do some reading.

Comment: As for the basics: this would be a good start: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7943